# Prove the inequality $x \le x+(1-x) \sin^2(x) \le 1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ by using derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, derivatives

The problem: show that $x \le x+(1-x) \sin^2(x) \le 1$ for $x \in (0,1)$

I tried to solve it with the derivative and the inequality $\sin(x) \le x$ for $x>0$
thanks for helpers

Comment: We're you told to use the derivative explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
0 \leq (1-x)\sin^2 x\leq 1- x
$$
Then you can see that 
$$
0 \leq \sin^2 x \leq 1
$$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for derivatives. If $x\in (0,1)$, then $1 - x > 0$ and $\sin^2 x\ge 0$, thus $(1 - x)\sin^2 x \ge 0$. Consequently, $x \le x + (1 - x)\sin^2 x$. Since $0 \le \sin^2 x \le 1$ and $1 - x > 0$, $(1 - x)\sin^2 x \le 1 - x$. Hence $x + (1 - x)\sin^2 x \le x + (1 - x) = 1$.